# Ciphertext with incorrect length error when encrypted key received from Nodejs app

Tags: python, node.js, encryption

Need help here with PyCrypto in python. 
I am trying to decrypt the text which I get from node.js app.
This is how I can decrypt the key in nodejs

```
key.decrypt(<encrypted_text`, ‘base64’, ‘utf8’, ursa.RSA_PKCS1_PADDING)
```

However, when I try to decrypt same text using python `PyCrypto` module, I get error.

Here is more detail:  I am trying to decrypt that in python using this code :

```
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_v1_5
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Hash import SHA
from Crypto.Hash import SHA
from Crypto import Random
from base64 import b64decode

key = RSA.importKey(open('cert.key').read())
sentinel = Random.new().read(15+dsize)      # Let's assume that average data length is 15
text = b64decode(<encrypted_text>)

cipher = PKCS1_v1_5.new(key)
message = cipher.decrypt(text, sentinel)
print 'message =====>', message`
```

I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-180-a1b00798e108> in <module>()
     19 
     20 cipher = PKCS1_v1_5.new(key)
---> 21 message = cipher.decrypt(text, sentinel)
     22 print 'message =====>', message, '\n'
     23 digest = SHA.new(message[:-dsize]).digest()

/Users/skapil/.virtualenvs/dave/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/PKCS1_v1_5.pyc in decrypt(self, ct, sentinel)
    202         # Step 1
    203         if len(ct) != k:
--> 204             raise ValueError("Ciphertext with incorrect length.")
    205         # Step 2a (O2SIP), 2b (RSADP), and part of 2c (I2OSP)
    206         m = self._key.decrypt(ct)

ValueError: Ciphertext with incorrect length.
```